# How to fix running sveltekit error on vercel?

Tags: debugging, web, configuration, vercel, sveltekit

"How can I fix the error 'Failed production deployment' and other logic errors when deploying my SvelteKit personal website on Vercel? The website works fine on localhost, but encounters issues on Vercel. Can someone provide guidance on ensuring stable deployment of SvelteKit's code on Vercel? Code reference available at [insert link to GitHub repository](https://github.com/NVCDevelopmentTeam/My-website)."

Comment: I really hope you can help me get my site working properly and please leave what you fixed so I can learn from it.